# Using the REL attribute as a variable in JQuery

Tags: jquery

This might be a really easy question but I would like to grab the value of the rel tag in an image and store it as a variable to be used in a photo gallery script.

Here is what I started with.

```
var elem = $(this),
control = $('.slides_control',elem),
total = control.children().size(),
width = control.children().outerWidth(),
height = control.children().outerHeight(),
next = 0, prev = 0, number = 0, current = 0, loaded, active, clicked, position, direction;
backgroundColor = $(img[rel])
```

This is just a snippit of the code but what I'm trying to do is use the rel tag to store a background color for the entire page that matches the background of the image.

Is this the right way to capture the value of the rel tag??

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer to use ["attr"](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) operator, for example :

```
$("#image_id").attr("rel");
```

Answer (score 1):

you can get it like this right

```
var getvalue = $('img').attr('rel');
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like `$(img).attr('rel');`.

Answer (score 1):

If you have control over the markup, I'd suggest using data- attributes, which work well with jQuery 1.4.2's new changes to the .data() method:

```
<img data-background="#fff" />

<script type="text/javascript">
  var bgColor = $('img').data('background');

  $(body).css('background', bgColor);
</script>
```